# Google Geocoding API upcoming change announcements

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Is there a mailing list, beta API or other service (free or paid) that provides advance warning of changes to the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)?

The [blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/) and mailing lists provide notice of changes as they're released, but no advance warning. This can cause issues when, for example, address component types are added or changed without warning.